# Redshift count number of Mondays in a given time range

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I want to use Redshift to count the number of Mondays in a given time range. I've tried using date_part, which returns the day of the week. I can't use a simple count as there are multiple instances on the same day.

Comment: can you add some code that you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

if you have dates table reference you can use the following code

```
select count(distinct my_table.date)
from my_table
where 
date_part(dow,my_table.date)=1
and my_table.date between '2015-01-01' and '2016-01-01'
```

in this case the query will count all Mondays during 2015,

you can change the dates range the the day week .

```
date_part(dow,my_table.date)=1 -- Monday
date_part(dow,my_table.date)=2 -- Tuesday
```

and so on

if you don't have dates table , you should create Cartesian product